# How to connect Preferences with Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Pretty new to Android Studio, and I'm having a problem connecting my CheckBoxs' in my preferences.xml with all my other activities so they act as settings for the application. I have set up everything just as the official page (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) had said, but I still can't get everything to work properly.

Here's my Settings class:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

and my SettingsFragment class:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
     }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to switch music or sfx either on if checked or off if unchecked around the app, here is my preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="music check box"
        android:title="Music"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:id="@+id/checkMusic"/>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="sfx check box"
        android:title="SFX"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:id="@+id/checkSfx"/>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="notifications check box"
        android:title="Notifications"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:id="@+id/checkNotif"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now my MediaPlayer is located in an Application class so it would go around every activity. How do I go about all of this?

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: @pantos27 well my dude, I just can't get these checkboxes to do anything. I guess it's cool and all that they stay in the same state onDestroy(), but at this rate they're pretty much useless. I need to connect them to stuff and they're not letting me.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my MediaPlayer is located in an Application class so it would go around every activity

That may not be the correct pattern.

> How do I go about all of this?

Have the component managing your `MediaPlayer` (`Application` as it stands, possibly a `Service` sometime later) call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` on the `SharedPreferences` to find out about changes. Then, react to those changes as needed.

Comment: Still having trouble setting that method up, could you share an example or sample code? And how do I get my MediaPlayer to call the method? Thanks in advance man

Comment: @Mintoil: See [this class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.5/Documents/DocumentTree/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/documenttree/SettingsFragment.java) and [this class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.5/Introspection/SAWMonitorTile/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/sawmonitor/SettingsFragment.java) for samples that use `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`.

Comment: @Mintoil: "And how do I get my MediaPlayer to call the method?" -- your custom subclass of `Application` can call `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, and on that `SharedPreferences` call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangedListener()`. That `Application` presumably has access to your `MediaPlayer` and can tell it what to do, based on the changes to your `SharedPreferences`.